# Pygame: is this the right event for seeing if a mousebutton is pressed

Tags: python, pygame, right-mouse-button

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    print("MOUSEBUTTON")
```

Is this the right event for Mouse button pressed?

Answer (score 1):

To see if mouse button was pressed you use `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `event.button`.

To see if mouse button is held pressed use [pygame.mouse.get_pressed()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed)

It is similar to `KEYDOWN` ad `pygame.key.get_pressed()` on this image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html) (boldface mine):

> The mouse buttons generate **`pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`** and `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` events when they are pressed and released.